# algolia search by attribute in laravel plugin (optionally)

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

```
Route::get('delete_project/{project_id}', function($project_id){

    $project = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->projects()->where('project_id', $project_id)->get()->first();
    $index = Algolia::connection('main')->initIndex(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->email);

    $result = $index->search($project->name, array('facetFilters' => 'project.name') );
    dd($result);

    $project->delete();

})->middleware('auth');
```

The dd return either nothing or all of my algolia items, I want to take only the one that are with project.id of $project->id.

I have the following structure:

1. I have a projects_issues relation
2. When a user created a new issue, the issue is save to algolia with an index his email address
3. when a user deleted a project all issues are deleted from the server and I need to be delated from algolia as well. Algolia is experimental for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be something like:

`$result = $index->search("", ['facetFilters' => ['project.name:'.$project->name]]);`

"" as a query will match everything
but facetFilters will filter to only records that have the good project name

Answer (score 1):

Try using the numericFilters: https://www.algolia.com/doc/ruby#numeric-search-parameters

```
$args = [
    'facetFilters' => 'project.name',
    'numericFilters' => 'id=' . $project->id
];

$result = $index->search($project->name, $args);
```

Comment: This doesn't help. I will show you why! I have a little more posted on the question